# Как правильнее сделать бордер под текстом?

Tags: html, css

Хочу спросить как правильно сделать бордер под текстом на всю ширину?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.logo {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #070707;
    margin-right: 150px;
    
    
    
}

.header-line {
    padding-top: 32px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    
    
}

.header-line::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -32px;
    width: 870px;
    margin-left: -150px;
  border: 1px solid #828282
    
    
}

.nav-item {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: grey;
    margin-right: 150px;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header-line">
                <div class="logo">Home</div>
                <nav>
                    <a class="nav-item" href="">About me</a>
                    <a class="nav-item" href="">Skills</a>
                    <a class="nav-item" href="">Portfolio</a>
                    <a class="nav-item" href="">Contacts</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Тут есть "песочница" - вот в нее вставь `html` и `css` текстом.

Comment: Что не устраивает в своем подчеркивании?

Comment: @ksa: человек пока ещё сам не знает - просто задел на будущее :-)

Answer (score 1):

Делаем ширину псевдо элемента на весь экран, для этого пишем `100vw`, т.к. `1vw` = 1% от ширины viewport'а (Просто к слову, в CSS существует также единица измерения `vh`, где `1vh` = 1% от *высоты* viewport'а). И убираем `margin-left` чтобы элемент не сдвигался в лево. А вообще, советую ознакомиться с другими единицами измерения [на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Sizing_items_in_CSS#%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B_%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8E%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0), если же хотите ознакомиться более глобально, то и на это есть страница [на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B)

```css
.logo {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #070707;
  margin-right: 150px;
}

.header-line {
  padding-top: 32px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.header-line::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -32px;
  width: 100vw; /* Вся ширина экрана */
  border: 1px solid #828282
}

.nav-item {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: grey;
  margin-right: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-line">
      <div class="logo">Home</div>
      <nav>
        <a class="nav-item" href="">About me</a>
        <a class="nav-item" href="">Skills</a>
        <a class="nav-item" href="">Portfolio</a>
        <a class="nav-item" href="">Contacts</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: а если мне не на всю ширину экрана нужен бордер? я за место  width: 100vw; пишу свое значение? и возможно ли как то сделать бордер только под header (om) то есть под словами ?

Comment: `а если мне не на всю ширину экрана нужен бордер?` -- вы сами написали в вопросе, что вам он нужен на всю ширину. `я за место width: 100vw; пишу свое значение?` -- тогда ширина у него будет, та, которую вы написали. `возможно ли как то сделать бордер только под header (om) то есть под словами ?` -- полагаю что возможно, но нужно менять разметку и стили.